# Launching Multiple Instances of Eclipse RCP Product Application with Workspace Selection Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP product application, and I want to achieve a behavior similar to Eclipse IDE when launching multiple instances from the taskbar. Specifically, I'd like to:

1. Launch the first instance of the application from the executable (exe).
   The first instance should create a workspace within the same directory as the executable.
2. Launch additional instances from the taskbar icon, and I want each of these instances to always prompt the user to select or create a workspace, just like the workspace selection dialog in Eclipse IDE.

I've tried to add this parameter in config.ini
osgi.instance.area.default=@config.dir/workspace

And in my myapplication.ini
-vmargs
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/myappln-workspace

How can I achieve this behavior in my Eclipse RCP product application?

I'm using Eclipse Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)

Comment: You will have to write a dialog similar to `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog` and call it from your `IApplication` before calling `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench`.  Study `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication`  to see how Eclipse does it.

Comment: @greg-449, Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by implementing IApplication #start

```
public class Application implements IApplication {

import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceData;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog;   
@Override
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        Location instanceLoc = Platform.getInstanceLocation();
        // look and see if there's a splash shell we can parent off of
        Shell shell = WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(display);
        try {
            URL url = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "workspace").toURI().toURL();
            ChooseWorkspaceData data = new ChooseWorkspaceData(url);
            ChooseWorkspaceDialog dialog = new ChooseWorkspaceDialog(shell, data, true, true);
            dialog.prompt(true);
            String selection = data.getSelection();
            if (selection != null) {
                if (!instanceLoc.isSet()) {
                    url = new File(selection).toURI().toURL();
                    if (instanceLoc.set(url, true)) {
                        data.writePersistedData();
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        try {
            int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
            if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
                return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
            else
                return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
        } finally {
            display.dispose();
        }

    }
```

Also make sure to add required dependencies, In my case i added this 2 packages in  "Imported packages in Dependencies tab"

Import-Package: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide,
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application